# Dynamically add sub-categories to any category in the menu

Tags: functions, menus

I have a menu with a combination of pages and categories. I need to loop through the menu and if it finds a category automatically add all child-categories as a submenu.

```
Page 1 | Page 2 | Custom Link
                    Category 1
                    Category 2
                        Child Category
```

In the example above I need to dynamically add the Child Categories to this menu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can add them with the filter `wp_get_nav_menu_items`

```
add_filter("wp_get_nav_menu_items", function ($items, $menu, $args) {

    // don't add child categories in administration of menus
    if (is_admin()) {
        return $items;
    }


    foreach ($items as $index => $i) {

        if ("category" !== $i->object) {
            continue;
        }


        $term_children = get_term_children($i->object_id, "category");


        // add child categories

        foreach ($term_children as $index2 => $child_id) {

            $child = get_term($child_id);

            $url = get_term_link($child);


            $e = new \stdClass();

            $e->title = $child->name;
            $e->url = $url;
            $e->menu_order = 500 * ($index + 1) + $index2;
            $e->post_type = "nav_menu_item";
            $e->post_status = "published";
            $e->post_parent = $i->ID;
            $e->menu_item_parent = $i->ID;
            $e->type = "custom";
            $e->object = "custom";
            $e->description = "";
            $e->object_id = 0;
            $e->db_id = 0;
            $e->ID = 0;
            $e->classes = array();

            $items[] = $e;

        }


    }


    return $items;

}, 10, 3);
```

Comment: this is only giving me the sub-categories for the last category.

Comment: I made a mistake with indexes. I edit my answer, can you try again ?

Comment: Doh, I should have caught that as well. :) That worked, thank you. I started thinking that it might be best practices to add the parent categories as well. In other words, I add a class to the "Custom Link" (menu-item-all-categories) then in the function once it finds that class add all categories and subcategories to that menu item. Can you help tweak your code to handle this?

Comment: Hi @mmm any chance you can help me out with my latest issue?
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/282959/dynamically-add-child-categories-to-parent-categories-in-menu

Comment: @mmm hello, how we can change the code in order to select the level we want subcategories to be displayed?
for example in this menu
top
-submenu
–subsubmenu
if i select 1 level to show only top, if i select 2 to show top and submenu, is this possible? thanks