# How to remove or add submenu item on plugin activate or deactive

Tags: plugin-development, menus

I am trying to make a basic plugin and want to add or remove sub menu item on plugin activation or deactivation. I am trying to achieve this with `wp_get_nav_menu_items()`

```
   $menuLocations = get_nav_menu_locations();
   $menuID = $menuLocations['primary']; 
   $primaryNav = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menuID);
```

I have three menus Home About product. I want to add a submenu under product on plugin activation.

Comment: Custom menus and submenus are not saved in database but set at every page call. To create them, look theses 2 functions : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/

Comment: @mmm question is about navigation menus, not admin menu. :)

Comment: oh ! sorry. for navigation menus, I saw the function `wp_nav_menu_update_menu_items` but there is no documentation then it can be more difficult to do that (but not impossible)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add items dynamically at every page call, you can look this answer :
[Dynamically add sub-categories to any category in the menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/282861/dynamically-add-sub-categories-to-any-category-in-the-menu#answer-282888)

And to add an element directly, you can try that for a custom link e.g. :

```
// create the new element

$post = [
    'post_title' => "StackExchange " . date("H:i:s"),
    "menu_order" => 700, // position in the menu
    'post_type' => 'nav_menu_item',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
];

$menu_item_db_id = wp_insert_post( $post );

update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, 'url', "https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/");
update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, 'type', "custom");
update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', 0); // change to create a sub menu


// association to the menu

$menuLocations = get_nav_menu_locations();
$menuID = (int) $menuLocations['primary'];

wp_set_object_terms($menu_item_db_id, $menuID, "nav_menu");
```