# Dynamically display sub-categories on primary menu without adding them

Tags: categories, menus

Title says it all i guess.
All i need is not having to go on menu and add a sub-cat everytime i create a new one.

also, is it possible to order them alphabetically?

Answer (score 0):

Another user has provided [sample code in a separate thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/282861/dynamically-add-sub-categories-to-any-category-in-the-menu#282888).  Reading their code, it appears to be just what you're looking for.

Good luck!