# How to dynamically add custom taxonomy terms as a sub-menu of an existing menu item, using custom walker class

Tags: custom-taxonomy, menus, terms, walker

## Desired outcome

I have a custom post type and belonging to it, a custom taxonomy. I'm trying to get my child theme dynamically add the terms belonging to that taxonomy as a sub-menu under a certain list item in one of my theme's menus. The taxonomy is hierarchical, and I would like to add all terms of depth = 1, i.e. the first and second-level terms with proper indentation and the same styles as my current menu.

## My strategy

So I first thought of using the wp_nav_menu_items filter, but since there can be many terms and they are hierarchical, I instead thought it's best to go with a custom walker to extend the Walker_Nav_Menu class.

## The issue

The issue I've encountered is that when I try to call the get_terms() function inside the custom walker, it returns "Invalid taxonomy". I know for a fact that the taxonomy is registered and that there are terms in the database. It seems like the get_terms() is getting called before init when it's invoked in the walker class. Since the taxonomy gets registered on init, the taxonomy is invalid when the walker class is calling get_terms();

## What I've tried

So I tried to lift out the get_terms() function from the class and do the following:

```php
function get_mytax_terms() {
  $myterms= get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'mytax',
    'hide_empty' => true
  ) );
  return $myterms;
}
add_action( 'init' , get_mytax_terms() , 10 );
```

I even tried making the variable global, but it doesn't return any terms, and throws an error for the taxonomy being invalid. A var_dump still gives me "Invalid taxonomy" error. I read on, and saw in a comment at the codex (on the Walker_Nav_menu class page) that I need to use static functions, and did this inside the custom walker class:

```php
/**
   * Get all terms of tax mytax
   */
  public static function init() {
    add_action( 'init', array( get_called_class(), 'get_mytax_terms' ), 10 );
  }
  public static function get_mytax_terms() {
    $myterms = get_terms( array(
      'taxonomy' => 'mytax',
      'hide_empty' => true
    ) );
    return $myterms ;
    var_dump($myterms );
  }
```

That var_dump runs but still returns the "Invalid taxonomy" error.

## Edit

I tried changing my custom taxonomy to the built-in taxonomy 'category' and then my function works. Using 'mytax' it still gives me invalid taxonomy.

The custom taxonomy is registered with

```php
add_action( 'init', 'custom_register_taxonomies');
```

***I am now fairly certain that this issue is due to the `wp_nav_menu` call coming earlier than the registration of my custom taxonomy.***

## The questions

Is it safe to register the custom taxonomies earlier than on `init`?

Am I right in using static functions in the custom walker class, as described above?

Would it improve anything to delay the `wp_nav_menu` call, by calling it from a custom location in my child theme. Rather than letting the parent theme call it, and adapting my walker class and/or taxonomy registration function?

Am I on the right track here or am I missing something else?

## Current situation

I'm including my custom walker below. Any tips are greatly appreciated.

```php
/* ---- Add mytax taxonomy terms to menu ---- */
class Walker_Add_Myterms extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  // Insert a submenu
  function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth=1, $args=array() ) {
      // if the current menu item being output is parentmenuitem
      if( 'parentmenuitem' == $item->title ){
          // get all terms
          $myterms = get_terms( array(
              'taxonomy' => 'mytax',
              'hide_empty' => true,
          ) );
          if ( ! empty( $myterms ) && ! is_wp_error( $myterms ) ) {
              // start a new list
              $output .= '<ul>';
              // iterate over each type and add an li
              foreach( $myterms $myterm){
                  $term_url = get_term_link( $myterm->term_id , 'mytax');
                  $name = $myterm->name;
                  $format = '<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>';
                  $output .= sprintf( $format, $term_url, $name );
              }
              // close the list
              $output .= '</ul>';
          }
      }
      // close the parent li
      $output .= "</li>\n";  
  }
}
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location'  => 'expanded',
    'container'       => 'ul',
    'menu_class'      => 'expanded-menu sub-menu active',
    'walker'          => new Walker_Add_Myterms
) );
```

Comment: where do you call `wp_nav_menu` ? this call must be in the header template where the menu will show.

Comment: Well, the wp_nav_menu is called in the parent theme, which is twentytwenty by wordpress. I doubt there's any problem with the menu call. Also, the menu is already displaying just fine.

Comment: I try your class `Walker_Add_Myterms` and I don't have your problem with `get_terms`, the walker add the categories as expected. (problems come after that)

Comment: @Kaperto : May I ask which theme you tried my class with? And what problems did you encounter while using it?

Comment: I try it with twentytwenty with calling `wp_nav_menu` in `header.php`. the first problem is that `get_permalink` is for post, you have to use [get_term_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will modify the class and make another attempt :)

Comment: @Kaperto : I tried changing mytax to category and then it works for me too. Using a custom taxonomy, it still returns invalid taxonomy though. Can you confirm that you tried my class using the built-in category taxonomy?

Comment: I try with "product_cat" created by woocommerce and `get_terms` works.

Comment: I just have seen that you go on a dead-end with this walker because in twentytwenty you need to add a class to the parent "li" to add children. try this way of adding elements in menu : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/282861/dynamically-add-sub-categories-to-any-category-in-the-menu#answer-282888

Comment: @Kaperto : How is that a dead end? Adding a (CSS) class to the parent item is not a problem at all. I just add it like [this](https://imgur.com/a/rVVZr5x), and then target that class in my walker. However, it shouldn't be necessary, as my current walker runs at the right place. When I change from my custom taxonomy to built-in categories taxonomy, it runs fine and displays the categories under the right parent li. I think you've misunderstood what the issue is here. Using the wp_get_nav_menu_items() filter as you suggested is not what I want to do since it would require adaptation later on.

Comment: @Kaperto : Your first guess was right. The issue was that wp_nav_menu got called at the wrong place. (It was also called at the right place, but the wrong place took precedence and gave me the errors). Thank you for your comments and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. It's not very smooth, but at least it works as I want it to. Will have to do some refactoring.

The issue was that wp_nav_menu() got called earlier than the taxonomy registration. I had accidentally placed it in my theme-functions.php and forgotten about it, then called it again in my header.php . That's why it seemed to work, but I still got the invalid taxonomy error and a broken menu.

Here's the final walker class:

```php
class Walker_Add_Myterms extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    public function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth=1, $args=array() ) {
    // if the current menu item being output has class "uthyrning"
    if( in_array( 'parentliitemclass' , $item->classes ) ){
        // get all terms
        $myterms = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'mytax',
            'hide_empty'    => true,
            'parent'        => 0,
            ) );
        if ( ! empty( $myterms ) && ! is_wp_error( $myterms ) ) {
            // Insert a submenu
            $output .= '<ul class="sub-menu">';
            // iterate over each type and add an li
            foreach( $myterms as $myterm){

                $term_url   = get_term_link( $myterm->term_id , 'mytax' );
                $name       = $myterm->name;
                $li_id      = 'id="term-item-' . $myterm->term_id . '"';
                $li_classes = 'menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-mytax term-item-' . $myterm->term_id;
                $wrap_class = 'class="ancestor-wrapper"';
                $format     = '<li %s class="%s"><div %s><a href="%s">%s</a></div></li>';

                // Get child terms ,and if they exist, create sub-menu with term children

                $children = get_term_children( $myterm->term_id, 'mytax' );
                if( isset($children) && ! is_wp_error( $children ) && sizeof($children) > 0) {
                    $li_classes .= ' menu-item-has-children';
                    $child_items = '';
                    foreach ( $children as $child ) {
                        $child_term = get_term( $child, 'mytax' );
                        $child_item     =   '<li id="term-item-' . $child_term->term_id . '" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-mytax term-item-' . $child_term->term_id . '"><div class="ancestor-wrapper">';
                        $child_item     .=  '<a href="' . get_term_link( $child_term, 'mytax' ) . '">' . $child_term->name . '</a>';
                        $child_item     .=  '</div></li>';
                        $child_items    .=  $child_item;
                    }
                    $format         = '<li %s class="%s"><div %s><a href="%s">%s</a>';
                    $format         .= '<button class="toggle sub-menu-toggle fill-children-current-color" data-toggle-target=".menu-modal .term-item-' . $myterm->term_id . ' > .sub-menu" data-toggle-type="slidetoggle" data-toggle-duration="250" aria-expanded="false"><span class="screen-reader-text">Visa undermeny</span><svg class="svg-icon" aria-hidden="true" role="img" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="12" viewBox="0 0 20 12"><polygon fill="" fill-rule="evenodd" points="1319.899 365.778 1327.678 358 1329.799 360.121 1319.899 370.021 1310 360.121 1312.121 358" transform="translate(-1310 -358)"></polygon></svg></button>';
                    $format         .= '</div><ul class="sub-menu">';
                    $format         .= $child_items . '</ul></li>';
                }

                // END Child terms
                $output     .= sprintf( $format, $li_id, $li_classes, $wrap_class, $term_url, $name );
            }
            // close the list
            $output .= '</ul>';
        }
    }
    // close the parent li
    $output .= "</li>\n";  
    }
}
```

And I also ended up copying the template-part where the wp_nav_menu() is called, from the parent theme, and replacing the default walker_nav_menu class with my own extended class above.